# What's wrong with this PHP class constant declaration?

Tags: php

What's wrong with this code?

```
   <?php
    namespace DEMO;
    
    class Config
    {
        const PRICE = $_GET['alim'];
    }
```

Why I'm getting Error 500 for using $_GET['alim'] but If I use const PRICE = '100'; then It's Ok

Comment: Because it is a const which is defined prior to $_GET being available.

Comment: This is NOT a *Get Method* like you wrote in the title, it is a class constant.

Comment: Do not do this. If you do this that means you need to have the `alim` parameter set on every single web request you receive otherwise this code will break

Comment: Constants are seldom declared from user inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use only constant expressions in class constant definitions. You have to affect the value to `Config::price` in the constructor.

```
<?php
namespace DEMO;

class Config
{
    private $price;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->price = $_GET['alim'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest not using `$_GET` directly within a class, as opposed to using proper DI.

Comment: @Jeto Thanks, I published too fast.